# Why I Am Unable to Remove Text-decoration-style from Underline to None?

Tags: html, css

When I am trying to run this code on a local server m getting this error. I have already mentioned in code that text-decoration-style: none;
I am getting text decoration as an underline, I want to remove that.

```
<style>
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-decoration-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .navbar {
        max-width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>
```

[Image of the Error where m getting error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZPLp.png)

Comment: `li a { text-decoration: none; }`

Comment: This code is not working. BTW thanks for giving me some of your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using an anchors `<a>` inside the `li` then you should apply this to `a` not `li`

```
.navbar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-decoration-style: none;` is wrong syntax, you should instead use `text-decoration-style: unset;` a better approach would be to use **`text-decoration: none;`**

Also The `text-decoration-style` property is not supported by **Internet Explorer/Edge** or **Safari**.

For further usage and syntax please check this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-style.asp)